# Restrict s3_direct_upload to specific filetypes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a quick question. I'm using the s3_direct_upload gem to facilitate uploads to my s3 bucket. I'd like to restrict uploads to PDFs only. How can I go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the gem's documentation, [Jquery plugin options section](https://github.com/waynehoover/s3_direct_upload#options-for-s3upload-jquery-plugin).

It looks like you would add a `before_add` callback function that checks to ensure the filename ends in `.pdf`, and returns `false` if it doesn't.